# Visual Studio 2013 - AngularJS Basic Issues

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

### 1. Problem

For some reason I get in the Internet Explorer / Firefox an old version of the **list.html** file but as soon as I run the application with chrome, I get the proper output (see below).

**Output IE/Firefox** : http://oi57.tinypic.com/2a9vgue.jpg

**Output Chrome** : oi62.tinypic.com/2h7du9x.jpg

### 2. Problem

The JSON data from my created service isn't added to the body of the table.

**Test to consume the JSON data** : http://oi59.tinypic.com/v5whus.jpg

Thank you very much in advance.

I've got the following code:

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="TodoApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- Custom Java Script files -->
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/services.js"></script>
    <title>Amazing Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", [
        "ngRoute",
        "ngResource",
        "TodoApp.controllers",
        "TodoApp.services"
]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: "listCtrl", templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

**list.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Todo</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Due</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
            <td>{{item.Todo}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Priority}}</td>
            <td>{{item.DueDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService) {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos.query();
});
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('TodoApp.services', []).
    factory('todoApiService', function () {
        var todoApi = {};

        todoApi.getMyTodos = function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/Todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
        };
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browsers cache? Ctrl-R? It might be something different in Firefox I forget

Comment: Problem 1 is solved .. couldn't imagine that it was due to some temp data. Especially, because it happened in both browsers .. I am really sorry that I cant up vote your post .. :(

Comment: Added an answer you can mark as correct if you want!

Comment: I will do that as soon as I have my second problem solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a browser cache issue.

Simply do a hard-refresh to clear it, in IE it's <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>.

Firefox it's <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-R</kbd>.