# AngularJS - Using $resource and interact with a RESTful data source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I've had a problem in my [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143669/visual-studio-2013-angularjs-basic-issues?noredirect=1#comment37257155_24143669), that I couldn't consume my service.

After doing some research I could finally figure out a way to consume my service after all. Still I was wondering why my other approach with the javascript object as method container didn't work out. I have some guesses but can't find an appropriate solution.

Hopefully you guys can lead me on the right path.

### controller.js (Working solution)

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService) {
    $scope.todos = todoApiService.query();
});
```

### services.js (Working solution)

```
angular.module('TodoApp.services', []).
    factory('todoApiService', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
    });
```

### controllers.js (Not working solution)

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService) {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos.query();
    });
```

### services.js (Not working solution)

```
angular.module('TodoApp.services', []).
    factory('todoApiService', function () {
        var todoApi = {};

        todoApi.getMyTodos = function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
        };

    return todoApi;
});
```

Comment: Does angular's injection kick in for $resource on the 2nd service.js ?

Comment: Jep, it kicks in at the services.js.

Comment: Actually, it never really gets into the method "getMyTodos". Couldn't reach my breakpoint at the return $resource statement ..

Comment: If I set the breakpoint at the todoApiService.query() method and try to step into the method, I get to this update function, while the "clone" object is undefinied http://oi58.tinypic.com/2z6rqyv.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either:
**Inject `$resource` to your factory function**, just like you did in the working version. And then you can remove the `$resource` as a parameter for `getMyTodos`.

```
angular.module('TodoApp.services', []).
    factory('todoApiService', function ($resource) {
        var todoApi = {};

        todoApi.getMyTodos = function () {
            return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
        };

    return todoApi;
});
```

And then from the controller:

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService) {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos().query();
    });
```

**Or, you can pass the `$resource` from the controller to `getMyTodos` (after injecting it to the controller)** - so your controller would look like:

```
angular.module('TodoApp.controllers', []).
    controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $location, todoApiService, $resource) {
        $scope.todos = todoApiService.getMyTodos($resource).query();
    });
```

I didn't check to see that this is working, but it *should* :)

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. Kind of makes sense to add the parentheses, even though it looks a bit weird .. ;)

Comment: Well, it's a method that returns a resource. So you have to call it in order to get the resource that you want to query.  
You could implement it using a getter (if the parentheses really annoy you) but that's a different story and it's not quite the correct use-case for a getter.